# How do I direct a link to a page loaded into an iframe on another page and scroll it to location with a single click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**-- library.htm --**

```
<iframe id="libcont" name="libcontent">
```

**-- content.htm --**

lorem ipsum `<p name="scroll">lorem ipsum</p>`

**-- map.htm --**

```
<a href="content.htm#scroll" target="library.htm#libcontent">Read More...</a>
```

---

Goal: clicking on the link within "map.htm" leads to "library.htm"
with "content.htm" already loaded into "libcont" iframe and scrolled
to the paragraph tagged "scroll". I can't find a HTML/CSS solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using javascript:
The anchor leads to `library.htm`, the onload function of library loads the iframe and uses `scrollIntoView()`([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)) to scroll to the right place.

**map.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Map</h2>
    <a href="library.htm">Read More...</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**library.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
   loadContent = function() {
       var frame = document.getElementsByName('libcontent')[0];
       frame.onload = function() {
           frames['libcontent'].document.getElementsByName('scroll')[0].scrollIntoView();
       }
       frame.src='content.htm';

   };
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadContent()">
     <div style="height:1000px; background:gray;"> </div>
     <h2>Library</h2>
     <iframe id="libcontent" name="libcontent"></iframe>
     <div style="height:1000px; background:gray;"> </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**content.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
    <h2> Content </h2>
    lorem ipsum <p name="scroll">lorem ipsum</p>
 <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE: load different contents**

To achieve this we are going to use a query parameter('content').

**map.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Map</h2>
    <a href="library.htm?content=content1">Content 1</a>
    <a href="library.htm?content=content2">Content 2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**library.htm**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
     loadContent = function() {

     const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
     const content = urlParams.get('content');

     // Check if the query param 'content' exists
     if (content) {
        var frame = document.getElementsByName('libcontent')[0];

        frame.onload = function() {
        frames['libcontent'].document.getElementsByName('scroll')[0].scrollIntoView();

        }
        // Loads the content
        frame.src= content + '.htm#scroll';

      }
  };  
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadContent()">
     <div style="height:1000px; background:gray;"> </div>
     <h2>Library</h2>
     <iframe id="libcontent" name="libcontent"></iframe>
     <div style="height:1000px; background:gray;"> </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**content2.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
    <h2> Content 2 </h2>
    lorem ipsum <p name="scroll">lorem ipsum</p>
 <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**content1.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
    <h2> Content 1 </h2>
    lorem ipsum <p name="scroll">lorem ipsum</p>
 <div style="height:1000px; background:black;"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. May I bother you with two more questions? 1) Can this be modified to only preload content if the specific link opened the page (as opposed to the menu bar)? 2) Can it be written in a way that different links from "map.htm" load different contents? (content1.htm, content2.htm, ect).

Comment: You are welcome. For both your questions I suggest using a query parameter. For instance: <a href="library.htm?content=content1">Read More...</a>. On the script you check if "content" exists. if it exists you load the iframe with the page name passed as parameter. I will update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in **content.htm** use *id* instead of *name* for anchor:

```
<p id="scroll">lorem ipsum</p>
```

In **map.htm** use:

```
<a href='library.htm#scroll'>read more</a>
```

In **library.htm** use javascript to transfer the *hash* to the iframe URL:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('libcont').src = 'content.htm'+window.location.hash;
</script>
```

As result, the iframe will load as **content.htm#scroll** and scroll to the anchor.